# Operate Raspberry Pi Python Script / PHP Website from C# or Java

Tags: c#, php, python, raspberry-pi

I'm currently attempting to use my Raspberry Pi as a Garage Door opener. I have used code off YouTube, and it works, but I am trying to link it up with a native Windows Phone and Android app.

I want to run the Python Script through a button click on a native app on a Windows Phone / Android device.

Presently, I have a website with PHP hosted by the Raspberry Pi that runs a Python Script:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Garage Operator</title>
</head>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['OPEN']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/door.py");
}

?>


<form method="post">
<button name="OPEN"> Door</button><br>



</form>
</html>
```

Here is the Python Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import required Python libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Use BCM GPIO references instead of physical pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# init list with pin numbers

pinList = [2]

# loop through pins and set mode and state to 'low'

for i in pinList: 
    GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT) 
    GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

def trigger() :
        for i in pinList:
          GPIO.output(i, GPIO.LOW)
          time.sleep(0.5) 
          GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)
          GPIO.cleanup()


try: 
    trigger()


except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "  Quit" 
  # Reset GPIO settings
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

My first idea was to do a "virtual click" through C# or Java code that uses the PHP website. How would I go about doing this? Also, are there any better / more efficient alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your PI connected to a network?
1. if Yes: you can easily open the php code via the PI using its IP
2. If no, get a wireles dongle for the PI, create a hotspot with it so you can connect to it via a phone

If you want to develop a native app for it (android or windows), i suggest you try to make the PHP a REST API.

eg.

```
http://192.2.2.2/open  
http://192.2.2.2/close
```

Good luck with your project

Comment: Yes, my RPI is connected to the network, I've got the webpage with the button hosted on the RPI via Apache.

Could I access the python code directly?

If that's not possible, is there a way to setup a REST API without curl?